# How do you test flash[:danger] an other flash messages in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, flash-message

I'm writing an integration test for a controller that renders a page and drops a `flash[:danger]` message if the update action is not performed for X reason.

This is the test I came up with:

```
  test "#update should render correct page if not successful"  do
    subscription_cart = subscription_carts(:active_one)
    subscription_cart.stubs(:update).returns(false)
    assert_equal flash[:danger], 'Something went wrong!'
  end
```

I'm trying to test against that flash message but no matter how I write that last line I get an error:

```
Minitest::UnexpectedError:
NoMethodError: undefined method `flash' for nil:NilClass
```

I've also tried with different assert syntaxes:

```
assert flash[:danger], 'Something went wrong!'
assert_equal 'Something went wrong!', flash[:danger]
```

What is the correct way?

Comment: you need to call a controller action before you can test for flash.  `put some_path(some_model),
              params: { p1: "a value" }`

Comment: Ya I'm a bit disappointed that this is to baked into controllers that you can't test them separately. I'm making a flash view component, which takes in the flash as an argument, and does various things based on properties there. Really frustrating that you can't just instantiate a damned flash message!